# Select unique rows based on only some columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an SQL view, and I want to get unique rows based on only some columns.

1. If all other columns are the same (excluding A), duplicates must be deleted.
   and
2. If all other columns are the same (excluding B), duplicates must be deleted.

I used the code below, but it still gives me the max of A then the Max of B, and what I want is to get distinct rows excluding these two columns, and I want to keep these columns in the select function.

```
SELECT Name, Account, MAX(A), MAX(B)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Name, Account
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you post a data sample along with desired output (as text)?

Comment: The desired result is to get distinct rows, excluding these two columns, we can take one of the row values for these two columns, whether the first value, the max value, it does not matter,
The problem I am having is I am having duplicate values because these two columns have different row values, and I want to get distinct columns based on the other columns excluding these two columns.

Comment: if you want your question answered you should post a data sample and desired output (both as text, not images), so people willing to answer may have a clear idea what you're trying to achieve and can test their queries against your data sample.

Answer (score 0):

Have not tested, but is this what you are searching for?

```
select sub.Name,sub.Account,MAX(sub.prod) 
  from 
(
   select Name,Account,MAX(A) as prod from MyTable group by Name,Account
   union all
   select Name,Account,MAX(B) as prod from MyTable group by Name,Account
) as sub
group by sub.Name, sub.Account
```